# round up/ round down a momentjs moment to nearest minute

Tags: javascript, time, momentjs

How do you round up/ round down a [momentjs](http://momentjs.com/docs/) moment to nearest minute?

I have checked the [docs](http://momentjs.com/docs/), but there doesn't appear to be a method for this.

Note that I do not want a string rounded to the nearest minute, I want a `moment` returned (or modified in place, either is fine). I prefer not to have to convert to a string, and the convert back too.

Thanks.

---

As requested, here is some code:

```
var now = new moment(new Date());

if (now.seconds() > 0) {
    now.add('minutes', -1);
}

now.seconds(0);
```

as you can see, I have managed to manually round down the moment here, but it seems rather hacky. Just after a more elegant way of accomplishing this.

Comment: Could we see some JavaScript? So we can see what format your moment is in.

Comment: @Shawn31313 Just the standard moment, but I'll add some js anyway to be explicit

Answer (score 121, accepted):

To round up, you need to add a minute and then [round it down](http://momentjs.com/docs/#/manipulating/start-of/). To round down, just use the `startOf` method.

Note the use of a ternary operator to check if the time should be rounded (*for instance, 13:00:00 on the dot doesn't need to be rounded*).

### Round up/down to the nearest minute

```
var m = moment('2017-02-17 12:01:01');
var roundDown = m.startOf('minute');
console.log(roundDown.toString()); // outputs Tue Feb 17 2017 12:01:00 GMT+0000

var m = moment('2017-02-17 12:01:01');
var roundUp = m.second() || m.millisecond() ? m.add(1, 'minute').startOf('minute') : m.startOf('minute');
console.log(roundUp.toString());  // outputs Tue Feb 17 2017 12:02:00 GMT+0000
```

### Round up/down to the nearest hour

```
var m = moment('2017-02-17 12:59:59');
var roundDown = m.startOf('hour');
console.log(roundDown.toString()); // outputs Tue Feb 17 2017 12:00:00 GMT+0000

var m = moment('2017-02-17 12:59:59');
var roundUp = m.minute() || m.second() || m.millisecond() ? m.add(1, 'hour').startOf('hour') : m.startOf('hour');
console.log(roundUp.toString());  // outputs Tue Feb 17 2017 13:00:00 GMT+0000
```

Comment: This method for rounding up is not a proper [ceiling function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Floor_and_ceiling_functions): `12:00:00` if rounded up to the hour gives `13:00:00`. See [my answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/37685886/2701578) for more details and a possible fix.

Comment: thanks for flagging this up @remeika — answer updated accordingly

Comment: Why not use 'endOf' method (http://momentjs.com/docs/#/manipulating/end-of/)? It's available since the same version as 'startOf'

Comment: @KirillGamazkov it's identical, you can do the same by doing it the other way around: `var roundUp = m.second() || m.millisecond() ? m.endOf('minute').add(1, 'millisecond') : m.startOf('minute');`

Comment: @KirillGamazkov The [endOf](http://momentjs.com/docs/#/manipulating/end-of/) function creates values like "2019-10-11T18:59:59.999" which you may want to be "2019-10-11T19:00:00.000".

Answer (score 27):

Partial answer:

To round down to nearest moment minute:

```
var m = moment();
m.startOf('minute');
```

However, the equivalent for rounding up, `endOf`, doesn't quite give the expected result.

Comment: for rounding up could maybe use `m.add(30, 'seconds').startOf('minute')`

Comment: @TommiKomulainen - that's probably not going to work. For example, if seconds=1, 31 seconds would still round down.  You could add 59 seconds instead of 30, but that still doesn't account for milliseconds.

Comment: @TommiKomulainen the method you recommend will do rounding to the nearest minute, which is exactly what the OP asked. See my answer below.

Comment: Can you explain what results you're seeing with `endOf`?

Answer (score 23):

Rounding to the nearest hour can be achieved by adding half an hour and then run .startOf('hour'). This is the same for any time measurement.

```
var now = moment();
// -> Wed Sep 30 2015 11:01:00
now.add(30, 'minutes').startOf('hour'); // -> Wed Sep 30 2015 11:31:00
// -> Wed Sep 30 2015 11:00:00

var now = moment();
// -> Wed Sep 30 2015 11:31:00
now.add(30, 'minutes').startOf('hour'); // -> Wed Sep 30 2015 12:01:00
// -> Wed Sep 30 2015 12:00:00
```

Comment: (1) it is a solution for hours, but the question is about minutes. Also, (2) the question was about `round up (ceil)` and `round down (floor)`, not about `round` with statistically best precision.

Answer (score 15):

The [roundTo feature](https://github.com/moment/moment/pull/1794) could make it into a future release.

Examples:

```
moment().roundTo('minute', 15); // output: 12:45
moment().roundTo('minute', 15, 'down'); // output: 12:30
```

Comment: Guess not. PR was closed. There is a [plugin](https://github.com/WebDevTmas/moment-round) though.

Answer (score 14):

## Rounding Down

Easy. As stated by many others, just use [Moment.startOf](http://momentjs.com/docs/#/manipulating/start-of/):

```
var roundDown = moment('2015-02-17 12:59:59').startOf('hour');
roundDown.format('HH:mm:SS'); // 12:00:00
```

Importantly, this also works as expected:

```
var roundDown = moment('2015-02-17 12:00:00').startOf('hour');
roundDown.format('HH:mm:SS'); // 12:00:00
```

## Rounding Up

Slightly trickier, if we want to round up with a proper [ceiling function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Floor_and_ceiling_functions): for example, when rounding up by hour, we want `12:00:00` to round up to `12:00:00`.

### This does not work

```js
var roundUp = moment('2015-02-17 12:00:00').add(1, 'hour').startOf('hour');
roundUp.format('HH:mm:SS'); // ERROR: 13:00:00
```

### Solution

```js
function roundUp(momentObj, roundBy){
  return momentObj.add(1, roundBy).startOf(roundBy);
}


var caseA = moment('2015-02-17 12:00:00');
roundUp(caseA, 'minute').format('HH:mm:SS'); // 12:00:00

var caseB = moment('2015-02-17 12:00:00.001');
roundUp(caseB, 'minute').format('HH:mm:SS'); // 12:01:00

var caseC = moment('2015-02-17 12:00:59');
roundUp(caseC, 'minute').format('HH:mm:SS'); // 12:01:00
```

Comment: The `momentObj.millisecond() != 1` check affects nothing: `moment('2015-02-17 12:00:00.001').subtract(1,'millisecond').add(1, 'minute').startOf('minute').format('HH:mm:SS') === moment('2015-02-17 12:00:00.001').add(1, 'minute').startOf('minute').format('HH:mm:SS') === '12:01:00'`

Comment: @Finesse You are correct, though funnily enough the equivalence code you provided ends up evaluating to false, unless you omit the latter one. ^.^ Anyways this check is not needed because the start of for a millisecond is the same regardless of whether you add an extra millisecond.

Comment: Sorry but truncate(x+1) is not equal to floor(x) when x is already a round number.
Also `ss` should be lowercase. Maybe try with an updated version of moment.

Answer (score 10):

A more precise answer:

```
t.add(30, 'seconds').startOf('minute')
```

Case1: Rounding down if seconds < 30

```
t = moment(); //12:00:05
t.add(30, 'seconds').startOf('minute') //12:00:00
```

Case2: Rounding up if seconds >= 30

```
t = moment(); //12:00:33
t.add(30, 'seconds').startOf('minute') //12:01:00
```

Comment: So far this is the best answer i found which will for my scenario :)

Answer (score 4):

I was searching for this same question and found a better solution:
Use the third parameter in `diff()` function:

`moment("2019-05-02 17:10:20").diff("2019-05-02 17:09:30","minutes",true)`

By setting third parameter to true, you get the raw value as response that you can round by yourself using `Math.round()`

See JSFiddle:
https://jsfiddle.net/2wqs4o0v/3/

Answer (score 1):

Just another possibility:

```
const now = moment();
// -> Wed Sep 30 2015 11:57:20 GMT+0200 (CEST)
now.add(1, 'm').startOf('minute');
// -> Wed Sep 30 2015 11:58:00 GMT+0200 (CEST)
```

Answer (score 1):

This solution worked for me;

```
function round_up_to_nearest_hour(date = new Date()) {
   return moment(date).add(59, 'minutes').startOf('hour').toDate();
}
```

Comment: Not correct: `round_up_to_nearest_hour(new Date('2015-02-17T12:00:30'))` gives `12:00:00` instead of `13:00:00`

Comment: @Finesse it worked for my purpose, not sure why it didn't work for you. No need to be rude and vote down,

Comment: I'm not rude. I've given an objective real life case for which your solution gives a wrong result (considering the question). Fix the solution and I'll revote it.

Answer (score 0):

The simplest solution so far:

```js
function floor(time, floorBy = 'minute') {
  return time.startOf(floorBy);
}

function ceil(time, ceilBy = 'minute') {
  return time.subtract(1, 'millisecond').add(1, ceilBy).startOf(ceilBy);
}

// The solution is above. The code below is an optional test:

console.log(
  floor(moment('2019-01-01 12:00:00.000')).format('H:mm:ss.SSS') === '12:00:00.000',
   ceil(moment('2019-01-01 12:00:00.000')).format('H:mm:ss.SSS') === '12:00:00.000',
  floor(moment('2019-01-01 12:00:00.001')).format('H:mm:ss.SSS') === '12:00:00.000',
   ceil(moment('2019-01-01 12:00:00.001')).format('H:mm:ss.SSS') === '12:01:00.000',
  floor(moment('2019-01-01 12:15:16.876'), 'hour'  ).format('H:mm:ss.SSS') === '12:00:00.000',
   ceil(moment('2019-01-01 12:15:16.876'), 'hour'  ).format('H:mm:ss.SSS') === '13:00:00.000',
  floor(moment('2019-01-01 12:59:59.999'), 'second').format('H:mm:ss.SSS') === '12:59:59.000',
   ceil(moment('2019-01-01 12:59:59.999'), 'second').format('H:mm:ss.SSS') === '13:00:00.000',
  floor(moment('2019-01-01 12:00:00.025'), 'ms'    ).format('H:mm:ss.SSS') === '12:00:00.025',
   ceil(moment('2019-01-01 12:00:00.025'), 'ms'    ).format('H:mm:ss.SSS') === '12:00:00.025'
);
```

```html
<script src="//cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/moment@2.24.0/min/moment.min.js"></script>
```