# Round moment.js object time to nearest 30 minute interval

Tags: javascript, momentjs

I was trying to round the moment.js time object to next nearest 30 minute interval. But looks my logic us wrong.

Ex:

```
10:13am -> 10:30am
11:45am -> 12:00pm
```

Here is my current code

```
start = moment();
minuteReminder = start.minute() % 30;
start.add(minuteReminder, 'minutes');
start.format("D YYYY, h:mm:ss a");
```

Comment: There are only 4 conditions, you can switch-case them.

Comment: You are finding the remainder, not the difference. You need to do both, as per my solution.

Comment: [This](http://stackoverflow.com/a/28561371/2393573) works for me, it's really good solution.

Answer (score 160, accepted):

Edit 2021 : [easiest solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69643727/7942242)

```js
const start = moment('2018-12-08 09:42');
const remainder = 30 - (start.minute() % 30);
 
const dateTime = moment(start).add(remainder, "minutes").format("DD.MM.YYYY, h:mm:ss a");

console.log(dateTime);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.20.1/moment.min.js"></script>
```

Million ways to do this. You don't need moment.js really. Anyway, here is one.

Comment: I think you are making a mistake , 
``` remainder  = (moment().minute()%30)-30```

Comment: I think it should be `code` 30 - (start.minute() % 30)

Comment: people that find this might want to include `.startOf('minute')` in order to reset seconds and milliseconds of the intrinsic date object.

Comment: This doesn't seem to do what was asked for. Even the sample snippet doesn't round 09:42 to the _nearest_ 30 minute interval; it rounds it to the _next_ 30 minute interval. The result should be 09:30, not 10:00.

Comment: The OP provided a number of examples in their original question, and this addresses those examples. The title of the post is ambiguous.

Comment: This solution is broken - it adds 30min. if the date is already rounded.

Answer (score 71):

Based on @Volune and @Cabloo answers and comments, an updated version can look like:

```
function round(date, duration, method) {
    return moment(Math[method]((+date) / (+duration)) * (+duration)); 
}
```

Which then can be used like:

```
var date = moment();
var roundedDate = round(date, moment.duration(15, "minutes"), "ceil");
```

Comment: Brilliant way to allow extended functionality!

Comment: Probably makes sense to restore the original timezone, otherwise this information gets lost. F.e. by adding .tz(date.tz()) to the end.

Answer (score 38):

A generic solution:

```
var ROUNDING = 30 * 60 * 1000; /*ms*/
start = moment();
start = moment(Math.ceil((+start) / ROUNDING) * ROUNDING);
start.format("D YYYY, h:mm:ss a");
```

You can change `ROUNDING` from 30 minutes to whatever you want, and change `Math.ceil` by `Math.round` or `Math.floor` if you want another way to round the value.

Comment: I like this one. You could convert the ROUNDING variable to a moment.duration(...), i.e. `function date_round(date, duration) { return moment(Math.floor((+date)/(+duration)) * (+duration)); }`

Used like so `date_round(moment(), moment.duration(30, 'minutes'))`

Answer (score 4):

You could do it with two ifs:

```js
// Current date
let now = moment();

// Getting hour and minute
let hour   = now.hour();
let minute = now.minute();

// Rounding minute on 30 mins interval
if(minute <= 30) now.set({minute: 30});
if(minute >  30) now.set({hour: hour + 1, minute: 0});
```

Answer (score 3):

You can do it by a simple if-else clause:

```
if(moment().minute()> 30){
    var myTime = moment().minute(30).second(0);
} else {
    var myTime = moment().minute(0).second(0);
}
```

Comment: Although the word `round` was used in question title, OP wants to have something similar to `ceil`. Your solution provides neither, it instead gives an effect of `floor`.

Answer (score 2):

For my case, I instead wanted something like

```
04-28-2021 20:00 => 04-28-2021 20:00
04-28-2021 20:30 => 04-28-2021 20:30
04-28-2021 20:11 => 04-28-2021 20:00
04-28-2021 20:35 => 04-28-2021 20:30
```

so the function below did the trick

```
function toNearest30Minutes(date) {
  const start = moment(date)
  let remainder: number
  const elapse = start.minute() % 30
  if (elapse === 0) {
    return moment(date).format()
  } else {
    remainder = 30 - elapse
    return moment(start).add(remainder, "minutes").format()
  }
}
```

The function above is just an adaptation of @jtromans answer higher above

Answer (score 2):

One-line solution

```
 moment().add( moment().minute() > 30 && 1 , 'hours').minutes( moment().minute() <= 30 ? 30 : 0).format("hh:mm a")
```

Working exemple :

```js
var min = moment().minute()
var dateTime = moment().add(min > 30 && 1 , 'hours').minutes(min <= 30 ? 30 : 0).format("hh:mm a")

console.log(dateTime);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.20.1/moment.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 1):

even though the question has been answered, I'd like to share my solution too.

```
var moment = require('moment');

const roundToNearestXXMinutes = (start, roundTo) => {
    let remainder = roundTo - (start.minute()+ start.second()/60) % roundTo;

    remainder = (remainder >  roundTo/2) ? remainder = -roundTo + remainder : remainder;
    const changedDate = moment(start).add(remainder, "minutes" ).seconds(0).format("DD.MM.YYYY HH:mm:ss");    
}

roundToNearestXXMinutes(moment(), 15);
```

EDIT: Thanks to Ishmael Sibisi for pointing to a flaw in my code! :)

Answer (score -1):

the code below rounds up the current time to the nearest 30 minutes and also flawlessly takes care of any trailing *seconds*

```
    var moment = require('moment')
    var main = Date.now() //2020-03-13T23:17:34+01:00
    var mainFormat = moment(main)
    var secs = mainFormat.second()
    var justMinutes = mainFormat.subtract(secs, 'seconds')
    var remainder = 30 - (justMinutes.minute() % 30);
    var dateTime = moment(justMinutes).add(remainder, 'minutes')
    var final = dateTime.format()
    console.log(final) 
    //2020-03-13T23:20:00+01:00
```