# MomentJS - making fromNow() round down

Tags: momentjs

I was using the following code to calculate the age of a person:

```
var year = 1964;
var month = 1;
var day = 20;
var age = moment(year + '-' + month + '-' + date, 'YYYY-MM-DD').fromNow(true);
```

The problem with `fromNow()` is that it rounds the number up or down depending on the decimal point. I would like it to only round down. In the above example the person's real age is 51 but it's returning 52 because his age is actually something like 51.75.

If I use `diff()` instead it rounds down which is perfect. But it doesn't give me the pretty text `51 years old`.

```
var age = moment().diff([year, month - 1, date], 'years');
```

My question is, is there a way to make `fromNow()` round down?

Comment: [This answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25323823/round-moment-js-object-time-to-nearest-30-minute-interval) might come in handy ;)

Answer (score 2):

You can configure a custom rounding function:

```
moment.relativeTimeRounding(Math.floor)
```

Answer (score 0):

The provided solution is correct but I thought I'd add a little explanation as this was the first google result.

Say I have a scenario where I want dates that were 1m 30s ago to display `a minute ago` rather than `two minutes ago`:

```
const minuteAndAHalfAgo = new Date();
minuteAndAHalfAgo.setMinutes(minuteAndAHalfAgo.getMinutes() - 1);
minuteAndAHalfAgo.setSeconds(minuteAndAHalfAgo.getSeconds() - 30)

moment.relativeTimeRounding(Math.floor);
console.log(moment(minuteAndAHalfAgo).fromNow()); // a minute ago
```

the `relativeTimeRounding` function takes a function as an argument which in our case is `Math.floor` which means the relative time evaluation will be rounded down. This can be found in the docs https://momentjs.com/docs/#/customization/relative-time-rounding/ - you can also specify a `relativeTimeThreshold` — the point at which to round the number.