# How to check whether the time is round figured to :00 or :30 or not in js?

Tags: javascript, time, format, momentjs

Accepted time should be like, Basically, it should be either 00 or 30.

```
9:00 AM
```

Not like :

```
12:34 AM
```

I can think of regular exp. Is there any other way ? I can use `moment.js`.
Any suggestions ?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Round moment.js object time to nearest 30 minute interval](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25323823/round-moment-js-object-time-to-nearest-30-minute-interval)

Comment: @shrys No, I just need a condition to find out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use the following regex to test your string:

```js
/^([0-1]?[0-9]|2[0-3]):[0|3][0]\s[A|P]M$/
```

[Sample](https://regex101.com/r/pzmHbx/10)

```js
const r = /^([0-1]?[0-9]|2[0-3]):[0|3][0]\s[A|P]M$/;

['9:00 AM',
  '12:30 PM',
  '3:30 PM',
  '5:00 PM',
  '12:30 PM',
  '12:34 AM',
  '3:21 PM',
  '4:56 AM'
].forEach(a => console.log(a, r.test(a)));
```

Comment: How can I edit the regex for single line compare like 12:30 AM ?

Comment: it is single line `/^([0-1]?[0-9]|2[0-3]):[0|3][0]\s[A|P]M$/.test('12:30 AM')` should give you true

Answer (score 0):

Use `moment`, you can use like:

```
const momentTime = moment(yourTime)
const minute = momentTime.minute()

if (minute === 0 || minute === 30) { // do your things }
```

But I think @shrys answer using regex maybe better.

Answer (score 0):

For each input like this, you can parse it with `moment.js` and query the minutes:

```
let times = [
    '9:00 AM',
    '12:30 PM',
    '3:30 PM',
    '5:00 PM',
    '12:30 PM',
    '12:34 AM',
    '3:21 PM',
    '4:56 AM',
];

times.map(time => {
    let parsedTime = moment(time, 'hh:mm');
    let minutes = parsedTime.minutes();

    if (minutes === 0 || minutes === 30) {
        // do stuff
    }
});
```