# The logic behind encoding of momentjs ._d property one hour early, especially in context of .endOf('day')?

Tags: javascript, time, momentjs

While writing [Rounding time duration of difference to end of day to whole hours in momentjs?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53951206/rounding-time-duration-of-difference-to-end-of-day-to-whole-hours-in-momentjs), I ran a few commands in Firefox console, and I just noticed this: when I specify a "naive" date, without any timezone, the ultimate Date recorded in the `._d` property of the moment is one hour early:

```
var m1 = moment('2017-02-17 21:00:00');
<- undefined

m1
<- Object { _isAMomentObject: true, _i: "2017-02-17 21:00:00", \
_f: "YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm:ss", _isUTC: false, _pf: Object, _locale: Object, _a: Array[7], \
_d: Date 2017-02-17T20:00:00.000Z, \
_isValid: true, _z: null }
```

So, I request '2017-02-17 21:00:00', I get `2017-02-17T20:00:00.000Z` recorded inside, in the `._d` property. Now, I'm in CET, which is UTC+0100, so I guess moment.js assumes I enter a local datetime when I enter a "naive" one, and converts it to UTC when storing it in `._d`.

That is OK, I guess, but what confused me is this in context of `endOf('day'):

```
var m2 = moment(m1).endOf('day');
<- undefined

m2
<- Object { _isAMomentObject: true, _i: "2017-02-17 21:00:00", \
_f: "YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm:ss", _isUTC: false, _pf: Object, _locale: Object, _z: null, _a: Array[7], \
_d: Date 2017-02-17T22:59:59.999Z, \
_isValid: true }
```

So I request end of day for "2017-02-17 21:00:00", and I get `2017-02-17T22:59:59.999Z`, - that is, the time portion is "22:59:59", which I simply cannot see as end of day ?!

Then again, if I forget about this, the code I have that uses `.endOf('day')` (say, in the linked post) works as expected.

Could anyone explain the logic how come this works - even if 22:59:59 is not really the end of day?

Comment: It seems to make sense to me. If `m1` represents a naive, *local* date and `_d` represents the UTC equivalent, then `m2` is the end of the *local* day (`23:59:59+1:00`), and its equivalent is in UTC (`22:59:59Z`) is stored in `_d`. Am I missing something?

Comment: The general idea is that everything is done relative to local time, but internally it stores the UTC time in `_d`. That's an implementation detail you shouldn't need to worry about.